# Apache CLI option value with whitespace

Tags: java, apache, ubuntu, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm using Apache CLI to parse command line arguments.  One of my arguments is a filter that takes a string `MyApp -f "search for this string"`

I thought when i do `cmdLine.getOptionValue("f")` it would return: `search for this string`

However it just returns `search`

What should I do to ensure that the entire string is retrieved, apparently just wrapping it in double quotes doesn't seem to work.

I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: Right now I'm treating it as an array of values (getOptionValues), then stitch them together to form the string

Comment: I am having same problem. Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I think passing the string with extra single quotes should work:

```
MyApp -f "'search for this string'"
```

Comment: From gnome-terminal, this doesn't seem to work for me, I would still get the option-value as just 'search. However if I supply the arguments from eclipse run config for Main, it works. Using commons-cli v1.2.

Comment: Does not work in bash/mac

Answer (score -1):

On Windows the argument must be surrounded with double quotes. On Unix you can use simple quotes, double quotes, or escape the space with a backslash.

Comment: This does *not* work on Linux (using commons CLI 1.4, which is the latest as of this comment)

Answer (score -1):

```
MyApp -f 'search for this string'
```

Enclosing the string in a single quote (') worked for me on UNIX.
This [comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLI-180?focusedCommentId=12712906&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-12712906) on the Apache CLI JIRA site might help.