# Apache CLI alternative with whitespace and quoting support

Tags: java, apache, parsing, command-line-interface, double-quotes

In one of my largest project, I've been using `org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser` for quite a long time. So long that currently, I have dozens of parameters in multiple exec classes.

Some time ago, I noticed that there is broken support for whitespaces and quoting. Simply said

```
--parameter="I need something like this"
```

or sometimes

```
--parameter="I would even appreciate espacing \"double quotes\""
```

Accoring to [Apache CLI option value with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839069/apache-cli-option-value-with-whitespace), this seems like an OS-dependent bug (on my Windows machine, parsing quoted argument works, but on Debian server, it does not).

So my question is: Is there any alternative which is reasonably similar to Apache Commons CLI (so I don't have to do complete rewrite), but supports quoting?

Answer (score 1):

[Picocli](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/) is an alternative for Commons CLI that is gaining in popularity. It has both a [programmatic API](https://picocli.info/picocli-3.0-programmatic-api.html) and an [annotations API](https://picocli.info).

Picocli has excellent support for parsing [quoted command line arguments](https://picocli.info/#_quoted_values).
Quotes around command line parameters are preserved by default in picocli, but this can be configured with `CommandLine::setTrimQuotes`. When [splitting](https://picocli.info/#_split_regex) parameters, quoted strings are not split (this can be configured with `CommandLine::setSplitQuotedStrings`).

Example:

```
@Command(name = "example")
class Example {
    @Option(names = "-x", split = ",")
    String[] parts;
}
```

If we give this command some input with quoted values:

```
example -x "-Dvalues=a,b,c","-Dother=1,2"
```

This results in the `parts` array having the following values:

```
"-Dvalues=a,b,c"
"-Dother=1,2"
```

Other picocli features that may be of interest:

- command line [autocompletion](https://picocli.info/autocomplete.html)
- usage help with [ANSI styles and colors](https://picocli.info/#_ansi_colors_and_styles)
- `@`-file (or "[argument file](https://picocli.info/#AtFiles)") support
- [strong typing](https://picocli.info/#_strongly_typed_everything) for both named options and positional parameters
- [subcommands](https://picocli.info/#_subcommands)
- `-Dkey=value` [map-like options](https://picocli.info/#_maps)
- [password options](https://picocli.info/#_interactive_password_options) (not echoed to the console)
- high-quality [documentation](https://picocli.info)
- actively maintained

> Disclaimer: I maintain picocli

Comment: This reads like an advertisement. You should state somewhere that you are the author of that library.